# Unexpected behaviour of vanilla Javascript looping function to select divs and add/remove classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

While trying to make a javascript slider on a web page I stumbled across a weird behavior of one of my scripts. Maybe someone of you can explain me why this has happened.

My HTML/JS to manipulate is:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var services = document.getElementsByClassName('services');
  loop(0);

  function loop(i){
    if (i == 0){
      var previous = services.length - 1;
    } else {
      var previous = i - 1;
    }
    services[previous].classList.add('out-position');
    services[previous].classList.remove('active');
    services[i].classList.add('active');
    setInterval(() => services[previous].classList.remove('out-position'), 1000);
    i == services.length - 1 ? i = 0 : i ++;
    setInterval(() => loop(i), 6000);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="services">
  <div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p class="subheading">Some text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="<?= imgURL ?>" />
    <p class="description">Some random text for description</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="services">
  <div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p class="subheading">Some text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="<?= imgURL ?>" />
    <p class="description">Some random text for description</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="services">
  <div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p class="subheading">Some text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="<?= imgURL ?>" />
    <p class="description">Some random text for description</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="services">
  <div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p class="subheading">Some text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="<?= imgURL ?>" />
    <p class="description">Some random text for description</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="services">
  <div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p class="subheading">Some text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="<?= imgURL ?>" />
    <p class="description">Some random text for description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I had two classes to play with; `active` was the class that I had to use to show a div and `out-position` was the class that I had to use to make the `div` slide to the right. All the animations were defined in my CSS.

Everything seemed to work fine at first sight but after some iterations I noticed that my divs started to act in a weird way. Looking at my dev tools i could see that after a couple of iterations my script was selecting more divs than what I thought it should and after something like 15-20 iterations was literally going crazy, selecting all the divs on every iteration and randomly adding/removing classes to them.

I made my slider with pure CSS now, and is working fine, but I would really love to learn from my mistakes. So, can someone explain me what I was doing wrong in this script please?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code sets up a new set of interval timers each time the function runs, and never stops the old timers.

Comment: To be clear: a `setInterval()` timer *keeps running* over and over again at the interval you requested. A `setTimeout()` timer only runs once after the delay requested.

Comment: I knew it was something easy to spot. I never changed setInterval in setTimeout. Sometimes you need another pair of eyes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution after @Pointy's comments, feel free to improve it, it can be usefull to implement a slider.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var services = document.getElementsByClassName('services');
  loop(0);

  function loop(i){
    if (i == 0){
      var previous = services.length - 1;
    } else {
      var previous = i - 1;
    }
    services[previous].classList.add('out-position');
    services[previous].classList.remove('active');
    services[i].classList.add('active');
    setTimeout(() => services[previous].classList.remove('out-position'), 1000);
    i == services.length - 1 ? i = 0 : i ++;
    setTimeout(() => loop(i), 3000);
  }
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}

.out-position {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="services">
  <div>
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <p class="subheading">Some text 1</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="description">Some random text for description 1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="services">
  <div>
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <p class="subheading">Some text 2</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="description">Some random text for description 2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="services">
  <div>
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <p class="subheading">Some text 3</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="description">Some random text for description 3</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="services">
  <div>
    <h2>Title 4</h2>
    <p class="subheading">Some text 4</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="description">Some random text for description 4</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="services">
  <div>
    <h2>Title 5</h2>
    <p class="subheading">Some text 5</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="description">Some random text for description 5</p>
  </div>
</div>
```